# Using wpf to animate ellipses consequently

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I have to implement a road junction simple program. The junction's image is set as the Background Property of WPF Grid and I have ArrayLists inside a Queue to represent the color of each car, origin street and destination street.
Now, I need to animate the cars as moving ellipses and I need each car to start its movement after the privious car gets out of the screen.
I am using the following code but it only animates first car.
What is the solution?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < queue.Count; i++)
        {

            ArrayList car = (ArrayList)queue[i];
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(car[0]);
            int color = Convert.ToInt32(car[1]);
            int from= Convert.ToInt32(car[2]);
            int to = Convert.ToInt32(car[3]);



                        Ellipse myEllipse = new Ellipse();
                        if (color == 0)
                        {
                            myEllipse.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green;
                            myEllipse.Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green;
                        }
                        else {
                            myEllipse.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Blue;
                            myEllipse.Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Blue;
                        }
                        myEllipse.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                        myEllipse.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                        myEllipse.Width = 45;
                        myEllipse.Height = 45;
                        myGrid.Children.Add(myEllipse);

                        DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
                        da.From = from;
                        da.To = to;
                        da.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                        TranslateTransform tt = new TranslateTransform();
                        myEllipse.RenderTransform = tt;
                        tt.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, da);
                         }
}
```

Comment: You're using WPF, which was introduced in .NET 3.0, along with ArrayLists, which have been obsolete since .NET 2.0 came out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WPF animation is is organized in other way.

I would suggest you to look at [Storyboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742868.aspx). Hope this will help you.

Comment: I'm not forced to use WPF. Are there easier ways to do this?

Comment: The downvote was unintentional - only realised it now after checking my profile. I can't undo it because it happened a few days ago so gave one of your answers a free upvote to compensate. Sorry!